# Deriving an array from other arrays with jq (cf. Python list comprehensions)

Tags: arrays, json, jq, blacklist

Given the following json containing two arrays:

```
{"zones":["dev01","dev02","dev03","dev04","dev05","dev06","dev07","dev08","dev09","dev10","dev11","dev12","dev13","dev14","dev15","dev16","dev17","dev18","dev19","dev20"],"disabled_zones":["dev01","dev05","dev06","dev08","dev10","dev11","dev12","dev13","dev14","dev15","dev16","dev17","dev18","dev19","dev20"]}
```

I wish to derive a third array containing items that occur in the first array but not the second:

```
{"enabled_zones":["dev02","dev03","dev04","dev07","dev09"]}
```

I would like to use `jq` for this task

In python I would use a list comprehension to achieve this:

```
>>> zones = ["dev01","dev02","dev03","dev04","dev05","dev06","dev07","dev08","dev09","dev10","dev11","dev12","dev13","dev14","dev15","dev16","dev17","dev18","dev19","dev20"]
>>> disabled_zones = ["dev01","dev05","dev06","dev08","dev10","dev11","dev12","dev13","dev14","dev15","dev16","dev17","dev18","dev19","dev20"]
>>> enabled_zones = [x for x in zones if x not in disabled_zones]
>>> print(enabled_zones)
['dev02', 'dev03', 'dev04', 'dev07', 'dev09']
```

I am currently trying to loop over items in array1 using `foreach` and checking if they exist in array2 using `in` but I'm struggling with the syntax.

How can I achieve this using `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) :

> As well as normal arithmetic subtraction on numbers, the - operator
>   can be used on arrays to remove all occurrences of the second array’s
>   elements from the first array.

this would do :

```
jq '{ "enabled_zones": (.zones - .disabled_zones) }' data.json
```

Comment: Wow, that is so easy.